# Where to find WebDriverManager "~/.cache/selenium" absolute path?

Tags: java, selenium, maven, selenium-webdriver

I'm using WebDriverManager via io.github.bonigarcia maven package. Based on documentation the following line of code places the latest chromedriver file in ~/.cache/selenium...

```
WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();
```

My question: What should be the absolute path for that relative path "~/.cache/selenium"?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Did my answer resolve your problem?

Answer (score 1):

`~` here is your user working folder.
For example on Windows based system the file will be located in:

```
C:\Users\yourName\.cache\selenium
```

folder.
So, if my user folder on my computer is called Prophet it will be

```
C:\Users\Prophet\.cache\selenium
```